# Cannot resolve Methods (Beginner issue in Android Studio (java))

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am following a tutorial in how to set up a Surface View in Android Studio using Java. This is my code:

```
package com.example.benjamin.labb3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class SurfaceView extends Activity {

    private OurView v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(v);
        v = new OurView(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isOk = false;

        public OurView(Context context){
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        public void run(){
            if(isOk){

            }
        }

        public void pause(){
            isOk = false;
            while (true){
                try {
                    t.join();
                    t = null;
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void resume(){
            isOk = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

In

```
setContentView(v);
```

I am getting the error msg:

> "Cannot resolve method
>   setContentView(com.example.ben3.pl2.SurfaceView.OurView)"

And in

```
  public OurView(Context context){
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
}
```

I am getting the errors:

> "Cannot resolve method super(android.content.Context)"
>
> "Cannot resolve method getHolder()"

Can anyone help me? The tutorial is from 2011 so it could have something to do with them having a older version of AS, or i just missed something perhaps.

Comment: put  v = new OurView(this); before setContentView(v);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things you should fix here. Rename your class and file to `MyActivity` or at least something other than `SurfaceView` to avoid confusion. You want to use the `SurfaceView` from `android.view.SurfaceView` not your own so you should import that one.

```
import android.view.SurfaceView;
```

Also, you must create a new instance of `OurView` before using it in `setContentView()`.

Here is your code with the changes applied.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private OurView v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        v = new OurView(this);
        setContentView(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isOk = false;

        public OurView(Context context){
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        public void run(){
            if(isOk){

            }
        }

        public void pause(){
            isOk = false;
            while (true){
                try {
                    t.join();
                    t = null;
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void resume(){
            isOk = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just try to instanciate your view before the setcontentview method
like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 v = new OurView(this);
 setContentView(v);
}
```

keep me up to date